# Genymotion does not find VirtualBox when run from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, virtualbox, genymotion

Using Ubuntu 16.04, Android Studio and Genymotion (latest versions).

Genymotion works perfectly when run directly, but does not work from Android Studio with the Genymotion plug-in installed. The error I get from Genymotion is "In order to work, Genymotion requires VirtualBox to be installed on your computer. You can download the latest version of VirtualBox from www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads.".

Of course VirtualBox is installed. Even tried removing it and installing again (v. 5.1).

Answer (score 3):

There is an odd issue with the Genymotion Android Studio plugin, which makes it impossible to start a device. This often manifests with genymotion.log containing error messages such as:

```
Output command: "/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage: ./libssl.so.1.0.0: version 'OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)"
```

It comes from the fact that Android Studio defines `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be `/android/studio/install/dir/bin:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which becomes `/android/studio/install/dir/bin:` if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set. This causes VBoxManage to try to load the libssl.so shipped by Genymotion, which is too old for Ubuntu 16.04 (because when `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ends with ":", the linker looks for libraries in the current directory)

You can do one of the following:

- Edit studio.sh to stop adding a trailing ":" at the end of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (I can provide more details if needed)
- Remove libssl.so and libcrypto.so from Genymotion install directory
- Define `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to some random value before starting Android Studio so that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` defined by studio.sh does end with ":"

Note that this has been fixed in Android Studio 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

After visiting the [Genymotion site](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Installation.htm), it might have something to do with the `dkms package`:

> Make sure that the dkms package is installed and that it compiles VirtualBox kernel modules each time a new kernel update is available.
> To do so, run **`sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv status`**.
> You should get the message ***"VirtualBox kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) are loaded"***.
> If not, force VirtualBox kernel modules compilation by running **`sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`**.
> Make also sure that you are part of the vboxusers group.
> If not, run **`sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers <login>`**.

Maybe it is caused because of the `dkms package` is not updated, so you are not able to use Genymotion from Android Studio but only running it directly.

Answer (score 0):

ok this took me some quality time to figure out take this step

1. locate your etc folder
2. cd into init.d
3. run virtualbox status:
   if it tells you that you need to install dkms package. then on a new terminal
4. sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
5. sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
   6.enter a password and renenter
6. then reboot and load to MOK(Your will get a blue screen that will ask to reload to MOK before rebooting)
7. Ok 
   your machine by now is rebooted
8. start your terminal go to etc/init.d
9. run virtualbox staus
10. I believe no errors
11. on a new terminal cd to your directory with genymotion
    13.cd into genymotion
12. run ./genymotion
13. congrats